# Find lastRow in column A-G

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here i try to get the last row in column A-G. In the column H I have formulas until row 300. When I run the script it paste into row 301 where the formulas ends.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
function Copy(){
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Hide");
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Oversigt");

  var values = ss1.getRange(2, 1, 1, 7).getValues();

  var lr = ss2.getLastRow();

    var values = ss2.getRange(lr+1, 1, 1, 7).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Right so I can’t make it past the data it into the next empty row in column A-G. There is column labels in the first row, so right now the first empty row is 2.

Comment: Perhaps you can share an example spreadsheet?

Comment: Absolutly:)https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14A0i6GKXi6_MDfaiLtW82GgIJzdyK6o1-JfL017ETto/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Copy(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Hide");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Oversigt");
  var values=sh1.getRange(2,1,1,7).getValues();//a single row with seven columns
  var lr=sh2.getRange("C1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getHeight();//Gets the height of column 1
  sh2.getRange(lr+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

[Range.getDataRegion()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataRegion(Dimension))